# How to query Firebase JavaScript 2.4.2 & AngularFire 1.2.0 to match an $id to another $id in a nested collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I have been working with Firebase for a few months now and just when I think I have a good working understanding, I get thrown for a loop. I come from a SQL background, so it has been a challenge working with NoSQL.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

When a end user selects a category from a select menu, I need it to bring back user profile data that is related.

**How my data is currently structured:**

I have a collection of "userProfiles". Nested within I have a collection of categories that the user selects for themselves. Here is an image:

[image]

There can be N number of user profiles and nested categories.

**The Code. Things I have tried:**

at one point I had a simple $firebaseArray setup and it was working. I am not sure why isn't anymore.

**Attempt #1**

Please note that "category" is a uid ($id)

```js
<!-- @ref = https://XXXX.firebaseio.com/userProfiles/-KHZmwpSwtI1GK5XyXnu/categories -->
var ref = fbRefDataService.userProfiles.orderByChild("categories").equalTo(category);
var fbArray = $firebaseArray(ref).$loaded(); // I have treid with loaded and without
$scope.userData = fbArray;
```

**Attempt #2**

```js
var ref = fbRefDataService.userProfiles;
ref.orderByChild("categories").equalTo(category).on("value", (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val());
  });
});
```

**Attempt 3**

```js
var qProfile = $q.defer();

var ref = fbRefDataService.userProfiles.child("categories");
ref.orderByChild("$id").equalTo(category).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  qProfile.resolve(snapshot.val());
}, function(errorObject) {
  qProfile.reject(errorObject);
});
return qProfile.promise;
```

I have been at this for days now. Exhausted all my known options. I am sure I am missing something simple.

I would be very greatful to anyone who could tell me what I am doing wrong, or point me in the right direction to be able to get user data by category.

Last notes:

I am using Ionic 1.3 and AngularJS 1.5.5

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found a solution to my problem. Knowing you can't use .equalTo() on a nested collection, I had it working with an earlier version. So I couldn't let go of trying to achieve the same result. It really must have been some edge case...

So my solution (and it is not the best one) was to load all my user data and then use my friend underscore in the Controller and custom angular filters in the VM to get the collection of data I needed.

I am just building a prototype so I needed something, anything to hack it together.

Here is the working code (Still a work in progress):

```js
function categoryChanged(category) {
  if (!category) return null;

  function filterCategory(data, key) {
    var findMatch = [];
    _.each(data.categories, function(value) {
      if (value.name === category.name) {
        if (data.length !== 0) {
          findMatch = data;
        }
      }
    });
    return findMatch;
  };

  var ref = fbRefDataService.userProfiles;
  ref.orderByChild("categories").on("value", (snapshot) => {
    var findMatch = _.map(snapshot.val(), filterCategory);
    vm.userProfileData = findMatch;
  });

}
```

Well, I hope this helps any other stubborn programmers out there. All the best.